# Cache video on Samsung SmartTV

Tags: html, caching, video, samsung-smart-tv

I'm have a webpage that is just a fullscreen video that I want to display on a Samsung PM32F SmartTv using the built in browser. If I have a internet connection this works fine but when I try to cache the video using a cache manifest to be able to show it offline the video will not play.
I have tried the same kind of caching with images and that works fine.

The video I'm trying to display is a mp4 file and is smaller then one of the images I have tried with so I don't think it's a size isue.
I do not have access to any kind of developer tools for the TV's browser so I can't check for any error messages.

The video is in a `<video>` tag.

Any kind of help would be much appriciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem that images will cache but video not. What's your working way of caching the video?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following script (I could not test it on real tv).

```
   function handleVideo(stream) {
     video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
     document.getElementById("videoElement").pause();
    }
```

Comment: what is stream? and what is video? could you please show more code

Answer (score 0):

After some time I found out it was just a simple server issue with a file that had been moved.